# Ilasm doesn't seem to include resources in dll

Tags: c#, ildasm, ilasm

I'm using ildasm.exe to decompile a .dll (e.g. myfile.dll) into an .il file, a .res file and several .bmp, .png and some other files. The latter image and other files are probably not included into the .dll file when using ilasm myfile.il /resource:myfile.res /dll.

How to include the images and other resources?

Tried using:

ilasm myfile.il /resource:myfile.res /dll

Expected image resources to be included. Judging by the filesize, this probably didn't happen

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to be specific about where these "several .bmp, .png and some other files" came from.  ildasm.exe does not generate them.  Some odds that you did extra work by decompiling the .resources file, thus trying to duplicate the .res file.

Comment: Consider using a tool like ILSpy.exe to have good insight in what's there and what might be missing.

Comment: Well, the ildasm I launched from the developer studio prompt probably put the bitmap files in there, otherwise I don't know how they got there. But thanks for the tip for ILSpy.